# Como agregar los valores de las claves de un array de objetos a otro array

Tags: javascript, array, poo, bucles

Se como iterar este array, pero no se como pasarle los valores de los objetos al otro array.

Usando el loop `for` agregar los valores

- de las claves `[{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{d:4},{e:5}]`
- dentro del array `result`

```js
let arr = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{d:4},{e:5}];
let result = [];

for(i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
    result.push(arr[0].a)
  
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: ¿Qué esperas como salida? ¿`[1,2,3,4,5]`?

Comment: los valores de los objetos asi [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: Buenisimo! graciass

Answer (score 1):

Como [Jaime](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/186586/jaime-men%c3%a9ndez) ha mencionado, puedes lograr el resultado utilizando `Object.values`. Puedes incluso conseguirlo en una sola linea de código con el método de array `reduce`.

```js
let arr = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{d:4},{e:5}];
let newArr = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => [...acc, ...Object.values(obj)], [])

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Por dar una solución más, puedes usar [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), y [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), para obtener en una lista cada uno de los valores de los objetos.

```js
const arr = [ { a: 1 }, { b: 2 },{ c: 3 },{ d: 4 },{ e: 5 } ];
const newArr = arr.flatMap(Object.values);

console.log(newArr)
```

Al hacer `arr.flatMap(Object.values)`, estoy diciendo que cada elemento de la lista `arr`, pase por la función `Object.values`, y devuelva el resultado. `flatMap()` se encarga de "aplanar" la lista resultante para que tenga solo una dimensión.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función `Object.values` para obtener el valor que tienen las claves de cada objeto y agregar cada valor de manera independiente a tu array original usando el spread operator.

Lo único que debes cambiar usar es `result.push(...Object.values(arr[i]));`. Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
let arr = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{d:4},{e:5}];
let result = [];

for(i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
   result.push(...Object.values(arr[i]));
}
console.log(result)
```